# Draggable Jquery Meter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have just started to learn Javascript and Jquery. I have been able to create a simple meter which shows random generated values. I am trying to make this meter draggable.

Here is my project.
https://jsfiddle.net/apoorvasomani/aLnvvn00/

Javascript Code -

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

HTML -

```
$(function () {
var gaugeOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },
    title: null,
    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// The speed gauge
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' + ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));

// Bring life to the dials
setInterval(function () {
    // Speed
    var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
        point,
        newVal,
        inc;

    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }


}, 2000);


});
```

I have searched google and most of them tell how to make an html element draggable and not something made using jquery draggable. Please help me here understand what needs to be done.